# Problema con envío masivo de correos electrónicos con PHPMailer

Tags: php, mysql, email, phpmailer

actualmente estoy desarrollando un sistema para enviar correos electrónicoa los usuarios registrados, pero cuando envío los correos si tengo 3 usuarios registrados se envía el correo 3 veces, si tengo 4 usuarios se envía 4 veces y así consecutivamente, entonces el usuario al final recibe muchos correos donde en realidad solo debería recibir 1. Estoy usando un while para iterar cada usuario y tomar el email del usuario para enviarlo. Algo así:

```
$emailReceptor = $instancia -> query("SELECT * FROM USUARIO");
while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($emailReceptor)){
 $asunto = $_POST["txtAsunto"];
 $correoCliente = $item['EMAIL'];
 $nombre = $item['NOMBRE'];
 $mail->addBCC($correoCliente, $nombre);


 $mail->isHTML(true);  
 $mail->Subject = $asunto;
 $mail->Body    = formato del correo html
 $mail->send();

}
```

El asunto es que tengo el $mail->send(); dentro del while, no sé si eso afectará o si puedo sacarlo del while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

por lo que entiendo que queres hacer es enviar el mismo correo a varios mails a la vez.
Para eso deberias agregar como copia a todos los clientes y el mail lo generas y envias una sola vez, te paso como hacerlo.

```
 $emailReceptor = $instancia -> query("SELECT * FROM USUARIO");

 while($item = mysqli_fetch_array($emailReceptor)){
     $mail->addBCC($item['EMAIL'], $item['NOMBRE']);
 }

 $mail->isHTML(true);  
 $mail->Subject = $_POST["txtAsunto"];
 $mail->Body = "formato del correo html";
 $mail->send();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Eso era todo lo que necesitaba!!!